# How can I subdivide large lists into sublists and use them to create new lists

Tags: python

I have 4 large lists of data that I need to split into 4 sublists and use them to create other lists that have elements from each group of the "master lists".
So for example I have my master lists

```
l1 = ['ability','able','about','above','accept','according',
'account', 'across', 'act','action', 'activity']
l2 = ['benefit','best','better','between','beyond','big','bill',
'billion','bit','black','blood','blue','board','body','book']
l3 = ['civil','claim','class','clear','clearly','close','coach','cold','collection']
l4 = ['detail','determine','develop','development','die','difference',
 'different','difficult','dinner','direction']
```

And I need to have 4 final lists that contain a balanced number of items with different properties from the initial lists, so in this example, every final lists will contain one fourth of words beginning with 'a','b','c' and 'd'. Each target lists will have therefore 1/4 of the 'a' list, 1/4 of the 'b' list, 1/4 of the 'c' list and 1/4 of the 'd' list.

Is there an efficient way to do this in python?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are the lists the same length?

Comment: No, they've got a different number of items

Comment: You could probably use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), but to be honest your question is not clear. Can you be more specific on how you divide those lists? It's hard to give a definitive answer when the question is so vague...

Comment: If they are a different length, how do you want to deal with the extra elements from some of the lists? A good example of sample input and output data would really help here.

Comment: i.e. Can you post a [mre], without those `...` but an actual input/output example?

Comment: Alternatively you could also transpose the data if you are planning to work in a numpy/pandas/... setting anyways

Comment: To be more specific, Each list contains a large number of items with different characteristics, I need to create sublists containing items from all categories. It is not important that the final lists have the same size, in the end they should vary by a couple of items at most, but the important thing is that the types are evenly distributed. Unfortunately I work with sensitive personal data, so I can't copy the actual data here, but I hope I have made my point.

Comment: No you didn't. We don't need your own data. We just need a [mre]. Please add any relevant information as an [edit] to the question. Don't count on comments' visibility

Comment: I am sorry but your question is still not clear. As a person trying to write an answer, I still don't understand how many items you want in the target lists. I assume something like `['ability', 'benefit', 'civil', 'detail']` but sounds like you want more there

Comment: No, excuse me if I don't explain myself. Assuming my master lists contains in total (l1+l2+l3+l4) around 800 elements, the targets will have about 200 elements each, but with all the 4 initials inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is!
The great zip() bulit-in function

```
l1 = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink']
l2 = ['apple', 'orange','banana']
l3 = ['coffee', 'tea', 'milk']
l4 = ['guitar', 'saxophone', 'piano']

for one, two, three, four in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4):
    print(one, two, three, four)
```

This outputs

```
red apple coffee guitar
yellow orange tea saxophone
pink banana milk piano
```

**EDIT**

Like how @Tomerikoo has commented, you can just do this

```
target = [item for item in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4)]

# Target is a list of tuples, so you can access each tuple like
print(target[0])
print(target[2])

# ('red', 'apple', 'coffee', 'guitar')
# ('pink', 'banana', 'milk', 'piano')
```

Comment: Can be just `for tup in zip(...): print(*tup)` to more easily support different amount of lists